# Showing selected country in a dropdown using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, drop-down-menu

On my page I have a dropdown menu with a list of countries, this is a page for users to update their address details so I would like to have the "selected" value when they visit the page set to what the entered upon signup.

I have

```
<option value="254" >Afghanistan</option><option value="255" >Albania</option>
```

Etc as my HTML markup and in the database the user's country is stored as the code like in the markup.

Normally this would be simple but as it is such a vast list of countries I can't write php code in each one manually.

Thanks

Comment: Did you really write the HTML code for 255+ countries like that by hand? You should have used an array for that at least and iterate through it to generate the dropdown.

Comment: @str I was actually given the markup for the page complete with a static list of countries with IDs. That does seem like the best option though I will have to motivate myself to type out all those countries unless there is an array somewhere premade.

Comment: http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/array-list-countries-en/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP to create the drop-down, simply insert the "select" test into the loop. (If you aren't, then you might want to - create an array of country vals or get from DB and create the options with a PHP loop.)

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the question as <kbd>MySQL</kbd>.
The answer is there:

Make a table called countries

```
Table countries
---------------
id integer auto_increment
name varchar(255)
code char(3)
....
```

And run a query like

```
SELECT name FROM countries ORDER BY name
```

Use the output in your dropdown.